# Galaxy Nexus and KitKat

Tags: updates, ota-update

Now that Android 4.4 aka KitKat is out, I couldn't find out whether Samsung Galaxy Nexus will get the upgrade or not.

Does anyone have any information on this?

I hope it will get it, this why I bought Nexus device in the first place.

Comment: I don't know if there's official information about this yet. But you can sign up (Bottom of the page) to get updates about Kit Kat [here](http://www.android.com/kitkat/). EDIT: Nevermind! See my answer.

Comment: You might also wish to take a look at [When will my device get the Android 4.4 update (KitKat)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56112/16575): Official: *Never* ([source](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3468085))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there will be [no official support for Android 4.4 on the Galaxy Nexus](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3468085). However, you will almost certainly be able to flash custom ROMs that are based on it.

There's some [supposition and explanation going on on Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/31/android-4-4-will-come-to-nexus-4-7-2012-and-2013-10-and-google-play-edition-gs4-htc-one-but-not-galaxy-nexus/). They make a few good points:

1. The Galaxy Nexus is old and well outside normal support windows.
2. The CPU Manufacturer doesn't even *make* CPUs for phones anymore - official kernel support from them would be difficult or impossible.
3. Google's relationship with Samsung isn't what it used to be. (Supporting 4.4 on the GNex officially would require them to work together again to some degree.)
4. Google's relationship with Verizon has never been good. Supporting 4.4 on the GNex would also mean the necessity to support it on Verizon's GNex - something that I'm sure neither Google or Verizon would be excited about collaborating on.

Comment: Google are apparently making the bizarre statement that " We’ve taken it and made it run all the way back on entry level phones. We have one version of the OS that’ll run across all Android smartphones in 2014.”. So the implication is that yes, you'll get it. I'll believe it when I see it, though.  http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/31/android-4-4-kitkat-google/

Comment: It will run on the GNex with no problem, certainly. But it won't be offically supported or provided by Google. [As officially stated by Google](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3468085). Support for that is now left to the community. The statement about running on entry-level phones indicates that they wish to expand the new version to new markets where flagship phones aren't practical or available, like where Firefox OS is targeting.

Comment: @Poldie, The decision to not offer official support was likely made based on business circumstances regarding Google, Verizon, Samsung and Qualcomm. It's not a matter of "The phone isn't good enough" at all.