# When will my device get the Android 4.4 update (KitKat)?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, android-versions

Android 4.4 (KitKat) was officially announced on October 31, 2013.

(You can review [the high level changes in KitKat](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html) at the official Android Developer's site or the [announcement on the official Android blog](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-for-all-and-new-nexus-5.html).)

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 4.4, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 4.3 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49832/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684/1465)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and **link to the source**
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

## Phones

### HTC

- **Droid DNA**

  - "HTC says it plans to update the handset to KitKat by the end of Q1 2014, 'pending certification from your carrier.'" [AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-reveals-more-kitkat-update-details)
- **One**

  - Google Play Edition: 2013-11-25 ([+Android](https://plus.google.com/+android/posts/L1kmDwTi2rG#+android/posts/L1kmDwTi2rG))
  - Unlocked and Developer models: 2013-11-29 ([@HTCUSA](https://twitter.com/HTCUSA/status/406487913615335424))
  - North American models: "Within 90 Days" ([AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-reveals-plans-speedy-htc-one-kitkat-updates))
- **One Max** / **One Mini**

  - "the update for both will arrive in the near future." [DigitalTrends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/android-4-4-kitkat-phone-list/)
- **One X** and **One X+**: *Never* ([source](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/01/htc-one-x-and-one-x-will-not-receive-kitkat-stuck-on-android-4-2-forever/))

### LG

- **G2**: December, 2013 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/android-4-4-update-for-lg-g2-to-arrive-in-december-20131105/))
- **Nexus 4**: 2013-11-19 ([AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/nexus-4-kitkit-ota-updates-are-starting))

  - Factory Image available [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occamkrt16o) and Proprietary Binary available [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#makokrt16o).

### Motorola

- **Atrix HD (AT&T)**: "Will be upgraded" ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Droid Bionic**: "Will remain on Android 4.1.2" ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Droid Mini/Maxx/Ultra**: "Will be upgraded ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Droid Razr HD Developer Edition/Droid M Developer Edition**: "Will be upgraded" ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Droid Razr M/Droid Razr HD/Droid Razr Maxx HD**: "Will be upgraded" ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Electrify M (US Cellular)**: "Will be upgraded" ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Moto G**: February 2014 [(AndroidCentral)](http://www.androidcentral.com/verizon-moto-g-now-receiving-android-44-kitkat-update)
- **Moto X**: "Will be upgraded" ([upgrade status](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))

  - Verizon: 2013-11-19 ([confirmed](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.com/2013/11/update-some-sweet-news-kitkat-comes-to.html))
  - T-Mobile: 2013-11-21 ([confirmed](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.com/2013/11/update-some-sweet-news-kitkat-comes-to.html))
  - AT&T: 2013-11-22 ([confirmed](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.com/2013/11/update-some-sweet-news-kitkat-comes-to.html))
  - Sprint: 2013-12-12 ([AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/sprint-s-moto-x-appears-be-getting-its-kitkat-update-morning))

### Samsung

- **Galaxy Nexus**:

  - Official: *Never* ([source](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3468085))
- **Galaxy Note 2 and 3**: no official announcement. [Rumoured to be](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/08/android-4-4-kitkat-update-predictions-galaxy-s4-galaxy-s3-galaxy-note-2/) after the Galaxy S5 launch.
- **Galaxy S3**: no official announcement. [Rumoured to be](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/08/android-4-4-kitkat-update-predictions-galaxy-s4-galaxy-s3-galaxy-note-2/) after the Galaxy S5 launch.
- **Galaxy S4**:

  - Google Play Edition: 2013-11-25 ([+Android](https://plus.google.com/+android/posts/L1kmDwTi2rG#+android/posts/L1kmDwTi2rG))
  - Sprint: 2014-2-13 ([Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2014/02/13/samsung-galaxy-s4-on-sprint-now-getting-android-4-4-kitkat/))
  - Others: no official announcement. [Rumoured to be](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/08/android-4-4-kitkat-update-predictions-galaxy-s4-galaxy-s3-galaxy-note-2/) after the Galaxy S5 launch.

### Sony

- **Xperia C**: never ([confirmed](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2606953/sony-nixes-android-updates-for-the-xperia-l-m-c-and-sp.html#tk.rss_all))
- **Xperia L**: never ([confirmed](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2606953/sony-nixes-android-updates-for-the-xperia-l-m-c-and-sp.html#tk.rss_all))
- **Xperia M**: never ([confirmed](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2606953/sony-nixes-android-updates-for-the-xperia-l-m-c-and-sp.html#tk.rss_all))
- **Xperia SP**: never ([confirmed](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2606953/sony-nixes-android-updates-for-the-xperia-l-m-c-and-sp.html#tk.rss_all))
- **Xperia Z**: planned, no date given ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia Z Ultra**: planned, no date given ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia Z1**: planned, no date given ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia ZL**: planned, no date given ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))

## Tablets

### Asus

- **Nexus 7**: 2013-11-13 ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/44860/android-4-4-kitkat-rolling-out-to-nexus-7-nexus-10-starting-today/))

### Nvidia

- **eVGA Tegra Note**, **Advent Vega Tegra Note**, etc. : [2014-02-18 - released](http://forums.evga.com/tm.aspx?m=2119024)

### Samsung

- **Nexus 10**: 2013-11-13 ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/44860/android-4-4-kitkat-rolling-out-to-nexus-7-nexus-10-starting-today/))

### Sony

- **Xperia Tablet Z**: planned, no date given ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))