# How to update/upgrade any phone to Android 4.4

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat

Variations on this question appear to be a common unanswered question; often they have a comment or two that I don't understand. I'm hoping someone can answer with some general background information, the concepts.

E.g. I see reference to "rooting". Do I need to root a phone before I can upgrade it? I've had previous Android phones that got auto-updated (either by the carrier or manufacturer: I just find a message that says: "a new update has been downloaded, click here to install"), and I didn't need to root them.

E.g. Can any smartphone be upgraded to Android 4.4? If not why not? And why might a manufacturer not want users to update their phones? Are some manufacturers more open to having phones updated, and some not? Does anyone keep a list of "upgrade-hostile" manufacturers?

E.g. does the phone being sim-locked (to a specific carrier) matter?

I'm not going to say what my phone is because that will distract from the more general answers I'm after.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks! Assuming that answer still applies for an update to 4.x to 4.4 then I think it is a duplicate. It is a shame that one never came up in my searches!

Comment: Direct link to the 4.4 list: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56112/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-4-update-kitkat