# HOW MUCH android OS TAKE MEMORY IN DEVICES

Tags: internal-storage

I need answer that how much memory would take any android os on devices.

can i root device and install kitkat os which device have already gingerbread .

Comment: That's a bit broad, as each Android version has different requirements. Additionally, different ROMs include different things, different hardware requires different driver-support, you might wish to integrate Google Apps as well (or not), plus several more things. So no generic answers possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one answer to this question: each device has its own build of Android, so Android takes a different amount of storage on different devices. Whether you can install KitKat on your device depends only on whether there is a KitKat ROM for it. See [When will my device get the Android 4.4 update (KitKat)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56112) and [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Rooting the device is completely unrelated. You don't need to root the device to install a new ROM, but to install an unofficial ROM you will need to unlock the bootloader. Usually you do this with the `fastboot` utility, but details are different for different phones. See [bootloader-lock](/questions/tagged/bootloader-lock) to learn more about bootloader unlocking.