# Will the Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 Nook receive updates past 4.4.2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-4, nook

I can't find official information from either Barnes and Noble or Samsung one way or the other. It doesn't look like it uses TouchWiz like other Samsung devices, so it would likely be more effort to develop and test for future Android versions. I think that if it is going to receive updates, it's at a really good price point for a tablet, with the Barnes and Noble sales and promotions happening now. If not, I'm not sure if it's worth the cheaper price to be stuck on 4.4.2 forever - it seems like that will be behind the times rather quickly. Are my fears of that well-founded?

Comment: Sadly the only answer is "I don't know." I have spoken to Samsung reps before and their official line is that "Samsung do not comment on future Android updates. While this may not be the answer you were hoping for, it is the only one at present." If they won't tell us then anything else is speculation, even if SamMobile or others have leaked videos, sometimes those never progress past beta.

Comment: related: [When will my device get the Android 4.4 update (KitKat)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56112/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-4-update-kitkat) & [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75684/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-5-0-update-lollipop)